# Jersey, Consume JSON array

Tags: ajax, rest

Hi Can any one tell me how can i handle this json in rest consuming method

On my client Side i have this code :

```js
var search_form_data_array = new Object();

search_form_data_array[0] = JSON.stringify({name: "dept",
    type:"equal",
    value: "233"});

search_form_data_array[1] = JSON.stringify({ name: "deptDesc", 
    type:"equal", 
    value:"depts" });

$.ajax({
    url: globalvars.otherDiscoveredSearchFormUri,
    type:'POST',
    data:{"SearchFormInput":search_form_data_array},
    contentType:'application/json',
    success: function(){}
});
```

My server side code:

```
@POST
@Path("/SearchForm")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getOtherChargesSerachData(SearchFormInput data)

    return data.name;
}

public static class SearchFormInput {
    public String name;
    public String type;
    public String value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XStream for reading as:

```
protected Object loadFromJSONRequest(String strJSON, Map<String, Class> aliasMap) {
    String aliasValue = "";
    try {
        XStream xStream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
        aliasValue = includeAliasesForRequest(xStream, aliasMap);
        return xStream.fromXML(strJSON);
    } catch (XStreamException e) {
        logExceptions(BaseResource.class, e.getStackTrace().toString());
        throw new PubGUIErrorResponse("error." + aliasValue + ".conversion");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logExceptions(BaseResource.class, e.getMessage().toString());
        throw new PubGUIErrorResponse("error.conversion");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from Google to serialize/deserialize json to/from Java objects.

To parse the array you can use something like this. Note that the parameter cannot be SearchFormInput, because as you are sending a dummy json object with a list inside it.

```
@POST
@Path("/SearchForm")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getOtherChargesSerachData(String data){

    // You will need to parse data if you want to send something more than the array

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<SearchFormInput>>() {}.getType();
    List<SearchFormInput> searchFormInputList = gson.fromJson(data, listType);

    // iterate searchFormInputList to do whatever you want

    return "Whatever string you want to return";
}
```

If you send it like this,

```
$.ajax({
    url: globalvars.otherDiscoveredSearchFormUri,
    type:'POST',
    data:{"SearchFormInput":search_form_data_array},
    contentType:'application/json',
    success: function(){}
});
```

you will need to get the array from value "SearchFormInput", and then parse it.
If you don't need to have this you can send just the array. Something like:

```
var stringArray = JSON.stringify(search_form_data_array);

...,
data: stringArray,
...,
```

Comment: Hi Nakib Thanks for your reply.Can you please suggest me how can i do it with JSON instead of using gson.

Comment: Hi Nakib can you please help how can i parse the same with out using gson.

Comment: Hi Nikib,I got the answer i need to add JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(obj); and i can iterate over this array to fetch the objects of that array.Thanks for your help.